Critical error when creating a simple window with gi-gtk
I'm porting a program to gtk3 (3.24.28) using the gi-gtk (3.0.39) module for Haskell but when I launch my program a critical error append :
(process:13364): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:07:59.826: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion '(((__extension__ ({ GTypeInstance *__inst = (GTypeInstance*) ((provider)); GType __t = ((_gtk_style_provider_private_get_type ())); gboolean __r; if (!__inst) __r = (0); else if (__inst->g_class && __inst->g_class->g_type == __t) __r = (!(0)); else __r = g_type_check_instance_is_a (__inst, __t); __r; }))))' failed

(process:13364): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:07:59.826: g_object_set_data_full: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(process:13364): Gtk-ERROR **: 09:07:59.826: Can't create a GtkStyleContext without a display connection
Trace/breakpoint trap

_gtk_css_lookup_resolve seems to be related to css.
I made a very simple program to find where this error come from and this very simple example fail :
module Main where

import GI.Gtk.Objects.Widget
import GI.Gtk.Objects.Window
import GI.Gtk.Enums

main= do
    putStrLn "a"
    window <- windowNew WindowTypeToplevel -- (AnotherWindowType 1)
    putStrLn "b"
    widgetShowAll window 

with the following message
a

(process:13387): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:10:35.188: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion '(((__extension__ ({ GTypeInstance *__inst = (GTypeInstance*) ((provider)); GType __t = ((_gtk_style_provider_private_get_type ())); gboolean __r; if (!__inst) __r = (0); else if (__inst->g_class && __inst->g_class->g_type == __t) __r = (!(0)); else __r = g_type_check_instance_is_a (__inst, __t); __r; }))))' failed

(process:13387): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:10:35.188: g_object_set_data_full: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(process:13387): Gtk-ERROR **: 09:10:35.188: Can't create a GtkStyleContext without a display connection
Trace/breakpoint trap

The "a" appear but not the "b" which seem to mean that the function windowNew is the problem. I also tried all different kind of WindowType but it doesn't change anything.
Do you know what is wrong with this program and how to fix it ?
I'm aware that gtk now use css to set gui styles. Could it be related to that ?

I have no idea, but your main seems to end immediately after displaying the windows. I'd try adding a threadDelay (10*10^6) at the end to see if terminating too soon is related to the issue.

I tried threadDelay but it doesn't change anything.

I had forgotten that Gtk had to be initialized with init and started with main at the end. As I'm migrating from Gtk2 and didn't found initGUI and mainGUI, I thought these functions no longer existed.
Now it work !
import GI.Gtk.Objects.Widget
import GI.Gtk.Objects.Window
import qualified GI.Gtk.Functions as Gtk
import GI.Gtk.Enums


main= do
    Gtk.init Nothing
    putStrLn "a"
    window <- windowNew WindowTypeToplevel -- (AnotherWindowType 1)
    putStrLn "b"
    widgetShowAll window 
    Gtk.main

